# Does this class setup violate the Liskov Substitution Principle

Tags: c++, inheritance, liskov-substitution-principle

I have this piece of code for a Tree. The BSTnodes contain the actual data. BST is a wrapper around them by inheriting from `unique_ptr<BSTnode<Key,Data>>`. BST doesn't add any new fields to the class.

The inheritance makes it so that my tree is a `unique_ptr<BSTnode>`, but is that a correct way of implementing it? The added operations for the BST like rotate() / insert() or remove() are specific to the data structure. You wouldn't and shouldn't expect them for a regular unique_ptr, but this does mean that a BST can't be used interchangeably with a unique_ptr.

If this implementation strategy is incorrect, how should I solve it?

```
template <class Key, class Data>
class BST : public unique_ptr<BSTnode<Key, Data>>
{
using unique_ptr<BSTnode<Key, Data>>::unique_ptr;
// operations ...
};

template <class Key, class Data>
class BSTnode
{
friend class BST<Key, Data>;

public:
//constructors ...

protected:
Key key;
Data data;
BSTnode<Key, Data> *parent;
BST<Key, Data> left, right;
};
```

Comment: The usual way to "solve" this would be to use *composition* where the class `BST` *uses* `std::unique_ptr` by having a member variable instead.

Comment: *"but this does mean that a BST can't be used interchangeably with a unique_ptr"* - no, it does not mean that. Liskov Substitution Principle would be violated only if `BST` couldn't be used or had different behavior when used by code expecting just `unique_ptr`.

Comment: So it is fine to add more behaviour as long as you don't change the inherited behaviour? Even if the added behaviour is publicly available and using it outside the context of the data structure would be meaningless?

Comment: Adding (or implementing) behavior is one of the primary points of inheritance. However the question of whether inheriting from `unique_ptr` is a good idea would be a separate question. Typically it would be better to use composition or (STL style) free functions, but it is not necessary because of the potential LSP violation. For example (STL motivation) use of free functions would allow those operations to be more generic and not depend on use of `unique_ptr` and make code more reusable when you decide to implement BST using `shared_ptr` / `intrusive_rc_ptr` / `objects_manger` or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LSP aside, inheriting standard classes is generally problematic and not a recommended solution for most cases. In this case, as @SomeProgrammerDude suggests, it's better to use composition and put the pointer inside your class:

```
template <class Key, class Data>
class BST
{
    std::unique_ptr<BSTnode<Key, Data>> root;
    // operations ...
};
```

Noone would want to use your BST class to replace the `unique_ptr` anyway. It's a separate data container that just happens to utilize `unique_ptr` to store its data.

Comment: The only problem I know of w.r.t. inheriting from standard classes is the unavailability of a virtual destructor and potential subsequent memory issues, if the derived class adds dynamic members. Is that the only thing or are there more problems?

Comment: @Str-Gen *"unavailability of a virtual destructor"* is not actually the problem, I would say that it is just a slight restriction prohibiting ownership of derived class instances through a pointer to base class instance.

Comment: @VTT Does that mean that `unique_ptr<BSTnode<Key, Data>>* ptr = new BST<Key, Data>()` would work, but fail to delete memory allocated for the extra bits of BST (if it had any), upon deletion of ptr? Or is the ownership restriction a broader thing?

Comment: @Str-Gen If `BST` didn't have any extra bits or custom destructor behavior then this code would kinda work. But it would in the manner of the "dodge the bullet time bomb".